# PHP LI Form Post and return Value

Tags: php

I am stuck on the last bit of this I have a list and when one is clicked the form submits.
What I dont understand is how to get the value of the item that is clicked.

How can i echo it or put it into a variable to use?
OR is there a better way to achieve all this?

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function submit(target) {
    document.forms['myform'].elements['target'].value = target;
    document.myform.submit();
    }

    </script>


    </head>

    <body>


    <form name="myform" method="post">
    <li><a href="#" onclick="submit('A');">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="submit('B');">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="submit('C');">C</a></li>
    <input name="target" type="hidden" value=""/>
    </form>
    </body>
```

OK I tried the following with jquery.
This seems to work in that it gives an alert with the value I need.
It doesnt seem to refresh the page - I need to get the value chosen so I can use it in a query in the page. 
How tdo I refresh the page and also put the value into a variable?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".inter li").bind(
        "click", function(){
            alert($(this).children("a").text());
        });
    });
```

```
</head>
<body>

 <div class="inter">
  <p>Liste des Produits</p>
  <ul>
      <li><a href="#1">P1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#2">P2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#3">P3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>



</body>
```

Comment: `echo $_POST['target']`

Comment: Why aren't you using radio-buttons or a select-box? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp  This would solve your problem, and you won't need your javascripit-Function

Comment: When i load the page I get Notice: Undefined index:

If i then click a list item the error goes away but nothing is echoed

Comment: @user1479891 Post your php-code. This message appears, when you access an array, and your index doesn't exist. I guess it happens, because you didn't select anything, and so there is nothing in your Array. But without the code, I can't help you.

Comment: It's a drop down menu so checkboxes arent really what i need

Comment: I have no more code - thats all i have on the page right now

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use this without javascript and use radio buttons with this. if you must use javascript try jquery.

Comment: If I could find an example I would

Comment: here it is a litle exaple     $("input:radio[name=theme]").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
});

Answer (score 0):

If you accept a `select-box`, this piece of HTML would solve your Problem:

```
<form name="myform" method="post">
    <select name="yourSelect">
      <option value="A">element 1</option>
      <option value="B">element 2</option>
      <option value="C">element 3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

You can also use `radio-buttons` with the same output:

```
<form name="myform" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="yourSelect" value="A"> element 1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="yourSelect" value="B"> element 2<br>
    <input type="radio" name="yourSelect" value="C"> element 3
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a `select` tag, then here's a better way:

### HTML

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="list">
      <option value="">Select a value...</option>
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>

    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

### PHP

```
// If the "submit" button is clicked
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // If $_POST['list'] is not empty
    if (!empty($_POST['list'])) {
        echo 'Selected list element: ' . $_POST['list'];
    } else {
        echo "You haven't selected an item!";
    }
}
```

[image]